# Como pegar a propriedade MemberNames com o index?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

Comecei a programar em C# a pouco tempo e estou fazendo um tratamento de validações utilizando o Data Annotation com windows forms, estou com um problema que não consego pegar a propriedade MemberNames da Interface IEnumerable pelo index, como posso fazer para pegar a propriedade de index 0, ou seja, a propriedade Nome.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Inclua o código na pergunta e não apenas uma captura da sua IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma vez que `MemberNames` é um `string[]` e você quer recuperar o primeiro valor do mesmo você pode explicitamente usar o índice 0, desde que você verifique se de fato o array foi inicializado. Outra opção é o método `FirstOrDefault()`, adicionando a referência da `System.Linq`.

```
var _obj = "";
var memberNames = error.MemberNames;

//Pelo índice
_obj = (memberNames != null) ? memberNames[0] : "";

//Usando Linq
_obj = memberNames?.FirstOrDefault() ?? "";
```

> Depois que você editar a sua pergunta, com o seu código é a classe que está validando, eu edito a pergunta com uma resposta mais completa.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta. Eu venho do VB e comecei a pouco tempo fazer algumas coisas no C#, por isso me enrolo as vezes. O seu exemplo funcionou perfeitamente com o Link, com o índice não funcionou, mas já funcionou da maneira que eu desejava. Vou anexar o código do exemplo, que é bem simples, só para você ter ideia. Vou aperfeiçoar um tratamento de erro melhor, pois estou utilizando as validações do Data Annotation para implementar no sistema da empresa que comecei a trabalhar e tem um sistema muito grande, que dá vários erros por causa do tamanho dos caracteres dos campos que não estão tratad

Comment: não estão tratados nos formulários, como há muitos campos e pouco tempo, vou utilizar as validações mapeando as próprias classes.
[Link do projeto](https://www.sendspace.com/file/gxuaxi)

Comment: A primeira opção não estava funcionando porque eu tinha escrito errado uma variável, está corrigido agora. Se a resposta solucionou o seu problema marque a sua pergunta como respondida.